# java chatbubbles right and left for firebase messages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I work currently on a messaging application on browser.
In my android app I can align the chat bubbles right or left , my question now how can i do this now in the web?

[Android Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aktJd.png)

[Web Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3smeB.png)

The Code for Web-Chatbubbles:

```
#messages {
overflow-y: auto;
float: left;
min-width: 100px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
height: calc(100% - 80px);
}
#message-filler {
flex-grow: 1;

}
.message-container:first-of-type {
 border-top-width: 0;
}
.message-container {
 display: block;
 margin-top: 10px;
 border-top: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
 background: skyblue;
 border-radius: 12px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Now my first question : How can i align the separate items left or right?

And my second question : In the image above the timestamp is not in the bubble how can i align it under the message end align end at the message end?

Current code for timeStamp:

```
  display: inline-flex;
  color: black;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: right;
```

Here is my HTML-Code for the message-list:

```
      <div id="messages">
        <span id="message-filler"></span>
      </div>
```

And here the JavaScript :

```
 if (!div) {
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = FriendlyChat.MESSAGE_TEMPLATE;
div = container.firstChild;
div.setAttribute('id', key);
this.messageList.appendChild(div);
}


div.querySelector('.timeStamp').textContent = '15:53';

var messageElement = div.querySelector('.message');
if (text) { // If the message is text.
  messageElement.textContent = text;
  // Replace all line breaks by <br>.
  messageElement.innerHTML = messageElement.innerHTML.replace(/\n/g,     '<br>');
} else if (imageUri) { // If the message is an image.
  var image = document.createElement('img');
  image.addEventListener('load', function () {
  this.messageList.scrollTop = this.messageList.scrollHeight;
  }.bind(this));
  this.setImageUrl(imageUri, image);
  messageElement.innerHTML = '';
  messageElement.appendChild(image);
}

setTimeout(function () { div.classList.add('visible') }, 1);
this.messageList.scrollTop = this.messageList.scrollHeight;
this.messageInput.focus();
};
```

Thanks in advance (:

Comment: Please provide a code snippet with html and css that you have tried so we can see what you are trying to do. Any answers would need a context, since what will work for one thing in one context may not work for multiple things in another context.

Comment: ok i did what you sayed

Comment: Whats your html structure for a particular message?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: So, you are just giving css, but what is the html for a message? How do you  display messages? What you will need to do is put the timestamp inside some sort of element that is nested inside of the message element. Then use `position: relative;` on the outer element and `position: absolute` on the nested element. Then use `top: ;`, `bottom: ;`, `left: ;` or `right: ;` to move the inner element to where you want it relative to the outer.

Comment: Do you mean that ?

Comment: <div id="messages">
            <span id="message-filler"></span>
          </div>

Comment: It's really hard to give you advice without you giving us some html to work with. Add a html snippet to your post with html/css and some test case messages.

Comment: sry but i´m a beginner :C I have added all the code in the question..